# TV cartoon show about a virtual world

Tags: story-identification, tv, cartoon

I remember a TV cartoon series about a group of students in an academy that discovered a factory with a super-computer inside. They entered it in some kind of teleportation tubes and they were transferred into a virtual world where they had to fight creatures.

Does anyone know what this is?

Comment: Hello and welcome to SFF! Can you take a look at [this guide](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question/9337#9337) and [edit] in anymore details you may remember.

Comment: Hi Sue and welcome to SFF.  I'm voting to close this question as a duplicate as per site policy, since there are existing story-identification questions for the same cartoon.  I just want to emphasize that this does **not** mean it was a bad question - we *like* duplicates, because they help people find the answers they're looking for, but we do want to make sure they're linked together for future reference.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Maybe it's [Code Lyoko](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_Lyoko)? Seems to fit pretty well.

[image: Code lyoko image]

Comment: Definitely Code Lyoko. Here's [a clip of the tubes](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vSRWKoSjflw) by the way. *Whistles virtualization music theme*

Comment: @AlexNevado Yes! It was that show! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 3):

Could this be *Cyberchase*?

> After being warped into Cyberspace from a library computer, Matt leads friends Jackie and Inez as Cybersquad. With live hosts Bianca and Harry, the team must protect Motherboard from the evil Hacker who wants to rule Cyberspace. Using gadgets and following clues, the team solves math mysteries and any other problem that comes their way.

[image: Cyberchase]

Comment: wow, that was another TV show I watched when I was little. I forgot about it!. Thank you! But no, sadly it is not the one I'm looking for :(